# So, do we say "practise the piano on me" or "practise the piano with me"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[In the dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/practise),

> **practise**: [intransitive, transitive] to do an activity, often
>   regularly, in order to improve your skill or to prepare for a test
>
> **practise something on somebody**  *Everybody wants to practise their
>   English on me.*

Also, [in the dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/play_1?q=play)

> **play (something) (with/against somebody)** to be involved in a game; to compete against somebody in a game

I am not sure if we can say "**I played the piano with him**"?

And "**He practised the piano on me**" or "**He practised the piano with me**"?

Comment: I think 'practice with' implies cooperative action and 'practice on' implies unilateral action. It's a difference between "Let's practice together" and "I will practice piano, and you will listen."

Comment: @AlexeyNekrashevich -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Is this question meant to be specific to British English?

Comment: @Jasper I guess not, but the spelling is British.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the phrasal verb with the verb "**practise**". "[**practise something on someone**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/practise-on)" means '*to do something bad or unpleasant to someone*'
according to Macmillan.

You can use it in some but not all contexts.

- Everybody wants to practise their English on me. - *means that everybody annoys me by testing their English skills on me.*

However, I disagree with Macmillan Dictionary that it's always something bad or unpleasant.
In most cases the person on whom someone practises is simply a test subject.

- I want to learn to be a barber. Can I practise on you? - *it doesn't necessarily imply doing something bad or unpleasant to a person.*

---

1. He practised the piano **on** me. - *means that you where either (reluctantly) listening while he was playing or he showed you how he plays the piano (which may have annoyed you) and you were testing his skills (especially if you are more experienced).*
2. He practised the piano **with** me. - *means that you were doing practice together, you and him.*

Comment: I'll give a strong second to the disagreement about "practice on" implying something is bad or unpleasant.

Comment: When someone is practicing their English on you, they're treating you as a sort of "sounding board", a language-piano, so to speak.  You're the instrument by which they improve their skills.

Comment: "Practice on" doesn't imply someone doing something unpleasant to you, unless helping someone learn something annoys you. For example, "I am learning massage - do you mind if I practice on you?"

Comment: You are all saying the right thing, I'm also curious as to why Macmillan's dictionary gives such a definition.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on one dictionary. It is also concerning that right above the entry, there is a link to "contribute to their open dictionary". That means that this entry might not have been written by a lexicographer. If there is only one entry for "practise on" across many sources then maybe it's just a verb + preposition instead of a phrase that needs to be defined as a single thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would use either form in this case. For me, practicing playing a musical instrument implies that there is no audience except the musician(s) him/her/themselves.

Let's say I have heard that you are learning the piano and I want to encourage you by offering to listen. I would say "please play something for me"

If I say "please practice the piano with me", I mean that I am also a musician and want to practice playing together.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two versions of the word "practice" (U.S.A. spelling) or "practise" (U.K. spelling?). A doctor will practise medicine on their patients who seek his expertise regarding their physical well-being.  So a doctor does practise medicine *on* patients. (Which may be pleasant or unpleasant, depending on the reason for visiting a doctor.)

A student of music may practise *on* a piano. However, if they are seeking the expertise or opinion of a teacher or fellow student, they might get together for the purpose of practising piano *with* them.

The piano teacher would be able to say in English:
"He practised the piano on the grand piano Room Number 3." because the student was doing this to a piano, playing on a grand piano, in Room 3. The teacher would also be able to say "He practised the piano with me." if the teacher and student were there together and the student was playing for the teacher, perhaps by the teacher's request. The teacher might also say directly to the student, "You practised the piano for me." either because the student performed their practice on a piano while the teacher was present, OR because it was clear to the teacher when the student performed on the piano that the student had practised piano, and improved, since the last time they were together.

Does this help?